# Android ftp connection issue

Tags: android, ftp

I have a problem using apache commons to connect to a ftp server

```
mFTPClient.connect("ftp://myhost.com/");
```

i get an execption

```
01-12 13:30:10.812: W/System.err(885): java.net.UnknownHostException: ftp://myhost.com/
01-12 13:30:10.812: W/System.err(885):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
01-12 13:30:10.822: W/System.err(885):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:280)
01-12 13:30:10.832: W/System.err(885):  at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:310)
01-12 13:30:10.832: W/System.err(885):  at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:189)
01-12 13:30:10.842: W/System.err(885):  at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:278)
01-12 13:30:10.852: W/System.err(885):  at com.brain.ftptest.FtptestActivity.ftpConnect(FtptestActivity.java:56)
01-12 13:30:10.852: W/System.err(885):  at com.brain.ftptest.FtptestActivity$1.onClick(FtptestActivity.java:35)
01-12 13:30:10.862: W/System.err(885):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-12 13:30:10.872: W/System.err(885):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-12 13:30:10.872: W/System.err(885):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-12 13:30:10.892: W/System.err(885):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 13:30:10.892: W/System.err(885):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 13:30:10.902: W/System.err(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-12 13:30:10.902: W/System.err(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 13:30:10.912: W/System.err(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-12 13:30:10.922: W/System.err(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-12 13:30:10.922: W/System.err(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-12 13:30:10.932: W/System.err(885):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The permissions for internet in manifest are set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Finally figured it out

The host name of my ftp was not being resolved to an ip

Once i gave the ip instead of name it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your internet connection is working on device or not 
i got same exception when my wifi was switched on but internet on my wifi was not working
i was not able to open anything on android